# PHPDoc, Factory @return type

Tags: php, polymorphism, phpstorm, return-type, phpdoc

Let's say I've

- an abstract class with with one abstract method.
- 2 child classes that define that abstract method in their own way.
- A factory that returns an instance of one of 2 child classes based on arguments.

Following is the sample code

```
abstract class Datalist{
    abstract public function render($arg1, $arg2);
}

class Datalist_Table{
    public function render($arg1, $arg2){
        /* do something here */
    }
}

class Datalist_List{
    public function render($arg1, $arg2){
        /* do something here */
    }
}

class DatalistFactory{

    /**
     * usual stuff
     *
     * @return Datalist
     */
    public static function build($args){
        $class_name = 'Datalist_' . $args['type'];
        return new $class_name($args['m'][0], $args['m'][1]);
    }
}

//in some other file
$list = DatalistFactory::build($args);
$list-> ....
```

**My problem**

My IDE (PHPStorm) does not hint on the `$list->render()`. My guess is that because it has been declared as an `abstract`.

**Question**
What should I put in front of `@return` in PHPDoc for `DatalistFactory::build()` so that the IDE hints on the functions defined in child classes as well.

**P.S.**

- I've tried instructions in following questions with no success
  [phpDoc notation to specify return type identical to parameter type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208482/phpdoc-notation-to-specify-return-type-identical-to-parameter-type)
- [PHPDoc: Is is possible to reference the object property descriptions from factory method docblock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053306/phpdoc-is-is-possible-to-reference-the-object-property-descriptions-from-factor)
- [PHPDoc preconditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582839/phpdoc-preconditions)
- [PHPDoc for fluent interface in subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563250/phpdoc-for-fluent-interface-in-subclass)

Comment: I dont normally use IDE, does it use the doc block to suggest methods and stuff like that?

Comment: You could have used [Metadata approach](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata) or use "DynamicReturnType plugin" .. but it will not work with your factory -- you are passing all arguments as an array instead of individual arguments.

Comment: Therefore -- either use already suggested `@return Datalist` (will give no hints for child-specific methods .. but will do for `Datalist` class methods) .. or provide type hint when `$list` will be created, e.g. `/** @var Datalist_List $list */` `$list = DatalistFactory::build($args);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to open this file in project. I use phpstorm 8.0.3 create new file in project and insert your code. All works fine =)

[image: code completion]

Comment: ah, so I need updating the software. Getting back to you shortly